# Unacceptable TLS certificate error in Termux proot-distro

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, flatpak, xfce4-terminal

I Installed Flatpak in Debian proot-distro.

```
$ apt install flatpak
```

When I run the following command I get Unacceptable TLS certificate error.

```
$ flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Error:

```
Can't load uri https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo: Unacceptable TLS certificate
```

I tried:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall  ca-certificates
```

But it didn't work, got the same error.

I'm using Termux, installed Debian 11 in proot-distro.

Comment: I just checked the issuer of this domain. `https://support.globalsign.com/atlas/atlas-tls/atlas-tls-ica-rotations`

Comment: Looks like it is misconfigured. When you try the https://flathub.org => let's encrypt, when https://flathub.org/repo/ => forbidden, and `Common Name (CN) dl.flathub.org
Organisation (O) <Not part of certificate>
Organisational Unit (OU) <Not part of certificate>
Issued By
Common Name (CN) GlobalSign Atlas R3 DV TLS CA 2022 Q`

Comment: @K-att- That's informative. Thank you. What is the solution now? Is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem based on the dl.flathub.org certification. When you check the `https://flathub.org/repo` site without the end backslash, the cert is: `Organisation (O) Let's Encrypt` it's OK.

With backslash, the query rerouted to https://dl.flathub.org/repo/ and the cert is 
 `Common Name (CN)   GlobalSign Atlas R3 DV TLS CA 2022 Q3`
Next step https://support.globalsign.com/atlas/atlas-tls/atlas-tls-ica-rotations

You need to install the correct certificate [from the globalsign site](https://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2022q3.crt)

The `sudo apt install --reinstall  ca-certificates` not worked, because the actual cert too "new".

Comment: Thanks. I added `gsatlasr3dvtlsca2022q3.crt` to 'usr/local/share/ca-certificates/fhub/' then updated it by running `sudo update-ca-certificates` it got added. But the same error again, `Can't load uri https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo: Unacceptable TLS certificate`.

Comment: Hmmm.... What is the output of  `openssl s_client -connect dl.flathub.org:443` ?

Comment: @K_att- Here's the [output Image](https://ibb.co/HYZZRKh).
I found the relevant information regarding flatpak in Termux. It's not supported as the below answers state,

1 . [GitHub - termux-packages/issues](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/9573)

2. [Andronix docs](https://docs.andronix.app/get-started/limitations/#container-applications)

3. [Reddit - Termux/comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/comments/epl9u5/how_to_install_flatpak_on_termux/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372942/ssl-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: I think you have self signed cert. Try the let's encrypt for example.